# Error deploying Solidity contract: Expected 0 constructor arguments, got 6 in hardhat

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, javascript, hardhat

I am trying to deploy a Solidity contract using a deployment script in Hardhat. However, I encountered an error during the deployment process.I'm using Hardhat as my development environment, and I have already compiled the contract successfully. However, it seems that there is an issue with the bytecode or data being provided during deployment. The error message I received is as follows:

`Error: expected 0 constructor arguments, got 6`

**Deploy Script**

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const {
  developmentChains,
  networkConfig,
  VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config.js");
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify");

console.log("I've reached here");

// Rest of the script...

const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"];
const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"];
const callBackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callBackGasLimit"];
const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"];

const args = [entranceFee, vrfCoordinatorV2Address, gasLane, subscriptionId, callBackGasLimit, interval];

//**Error starts here**!!

const lottery = await deploy("Lottery", {
  from: deployer,
  args: args,
  log: true,
  waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
});
```

// Rest of the script...

**Solidity Code**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AutomationCompatibleInterface.sol";

      abstract contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    // types/ enums
    enum LotteryState {
        open,
        calculating
    }

    // state variables
    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private immutable i_callBackGasLimit;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    // lottery variables
    address private s_recentWinnerAddress;
    LotteryState private s_LotteryState;
    uint256 private s_LastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_Interval;

    // events
    event LotteryEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestedLotteryWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

constructor(
    uint256 entranceFee,
    address vrfCoordinatorV2,
    bytes32 gasLane,
    uint64 subscriptionId,
    uint32 callBackGasLimit,
    uint256 interval
)
    VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2)
{
    // (Constructor implementation...)
}
//Rest of the code
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to the bytecode not being provided correctly during deployment. I have verified that the contract is compiled successfully and the bytecode is available in the artifacts/ directory.

Could someone please assist me in resolving this error? What could be causing the error during deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the abstract contract you defined in Lottery, remove `abstract`.(abstract contracts cannot be deployed directly.)

Comment: Thanks, @Ethan but I already tried that, **it throws an error and refuses to compile** and if I try making the constructor public, it logs that I am not implementing from the base contract.